A ghost movie from the 80s where the ghosts sink a yacht
I just remembered an old movie. I think it was from the 80s. It starts off with a navy captain marrying an albino woman to get her fathers ship, but on the honeymoon he sneaks off with the maid. The bride finds out and all three of them get killed in a fight.
Years later, a family moves into the house and the ghosts haunt them - mostly just by throwing stuff around, but they later sink the yacht of the family's visiting uncle.
The kids of the family try to bring peace to the ghosts, the husband gets the maid, and the jilted bride pushes the uncle off a cliff and hooks up with his ghost.

William Castle's ghost comedy The Spirit Is Willing with Sid Caesar and Vera Miles, though a couple of details are a bit off (the wife is not an albino and the movie is from 1967). From an online synopsis:

Ben Powell, his wife Kate, and their teenaged son Steve rent a New England seaside house for their summer vacation. Unknown to them, the house has been haunted ever since the day, 100 years before, that Felicity Twitchell accidentally met her death while axing her unfaithful bridegroom Ebenezer and their servant girl Jenny. The three ghosts, infuriated that their private domain is being invaded, go on a spree of destruction, for which young Steve is blamed. Although the spirits eventually materialize before Steve, his parents and his millionaire Uncle George persist in believing that he is a troublemaker. The situation becomes desperate when the ghosts sink Uncle George's yacht and Steve once more is held responsible.[...] Felicity becomes so enamored of Uncle George that she pushes him off a cliff in order to make him her ghost-husband.

Here's the trailer:



